# Habitual present and future

Tags: future-constructions

**Habitual present and future**

**1**.Habitual (regular repeated) action/
activity/state/condition in the present.
This regular activity commenced sometime
in the past and continues at present.

1.1.Present simple
*She swims regularly.*
1.2.Present continuous
*She is swimming every Thursday*. (not now)
1.3.Future simple- not typical use, but
acceptable
*She will swim with slow, languid strokes*.
(when she is sad or psychologically harmed).

**2**.Expected habitual (regular repeated)
action/activity/state/condition in the
future
2.1.Future continuous
*She will be swimming every day, when

we move to our new house in Florida*.

Can I use future simple?
2.2. Future simple
*She will swim every day, when we move

to our new house in Florida*.
If I can, what level of certainty it
implies?

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can but more usual is: She's going to swim every day when we move to Florida. "will" could be a parent talking about a child. This should give you all might need.

> Will is a modal verb. It is used with the base form of a verb. In
> spoken English and informal written English, the form won't is often
> used in negative statements.
>
> 1. MODAL VERB
>    *You use will to indicate that you hope, think, or have evidence that something is going to happen or be the case in the future.* I'm sure
>    we will find a wide variety of choices available in school cafeterias.
>    Will you ever feel at home here?  The ship will not be ready for a
>    month.
> 2. MODAL VERB You use will in order to make statements about official arrangements in the future. The show will be open to the public at 2
>    pm; admission will be $5.
> 3. MODAL VERB
>    **You use will in order to make promises** and threats about what is going to happen or be the case in the future. I'll call you tonight.
>    Price quotes on selected product categories will be sent on request.
> 4. MODAL VERB
>    **You use will to indicate someone's intention to do something.** I will say no more on these matters, important though they are.  In this
>    section we will describe common myths about cigarettes, alcohol, and
>    marijuana.  "Dinner's ready."—"Thanks, Carrie, but we'll have a drink
>    first."
>
> [Collins Dictionary_will](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/will#:%7E:text=Will%20is%20a%20modal%20verb,often%20used%20in%20negative%20statements.&text=You%20use%20will%20to%20indicate,the%20case%20in%20the%20future.)